# typescript overloading with generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gdwFzwGUMoMQAeFAVwFsAjEGAPgChl0sBPeAXnmqgAOACmwAaeAA8ejSQEp4AegXwyZALRr4AUQBKOgPI7mzEBIFIYWDBwEIdINEggA3EMCIlyAFRm8A3szw8HBQwKgQXJgklGj4AORwji5ucYHBIKHhXMAkUPhezAC%20xqbmlvDWtvD2AFbgpO7EpGQ%20PPABQSFhKBHwURgx8XB1YA2pnRndvQwwFgD8%20FowszBpXVnwOcQL8AXFJmYWVjYIAAogKMAAligA5h7Nrf5rkxv9g-Bxtpc3t%20PpmR62VyOz2JUO5UqCAe3l81QcTlcjU8LRkAB94SMGjDUfAMecfnccT5jAAzSgoUZXVB8QQtcQAVUYQn6IHw9iSSOJjHE-AEthg%20CEWzyu3k3BkDNk7IRyWRzSZzHJlIw1JQtIE9PgTJZTTZmPqbm5vMEAqFIvy4sl0oNoyNerIiuVVJpfK1OtZ%20AJ1yJDp8Jv5DHNuUt0m1Nu9vxxTopLvVbq8jOZnsIfp5GrN8GFIbFYal%20GjMg6fWwVwwYAAFlnWQA6d5oeTFoJgKBoBAJWVIuK4NJBCYDGDqpt9oL1oadlKiXsjzY5vkC3WeGsi2RTmfwYojlttz7DQ3AbvT-uUQftI99se7kBYyfnoIzCz4WsPmBr9ez4hPvXL3I8bi8ClQFJG43HgOZ4EAkBgJQUD8HnBhF1IH9iFXc9Nz7bd22%20H0-h7dc4AHIc7z6JoPi%20C4cLiN91wtEilxFP8AMuKCQOAMCIOY6DYIzBDaxXai%203Q4piiAA)

I'm not sure why Typescript thinks `x` type is `number | undefined` instead of only a `number`.

```js
declare const w: State<number>
const y = map(w, x => x) // <<-- ERROR

export type ResolvedState<T> = {
  readonly status: 'resolved'
  readonly data: T
}

export type RejectedState<T> = {
  readonly status: 'rejected'
  readonly error?: Error
  readonly data?: T
}

export type PendingState<T> = {
  readonly status: 'pending'
  readonly data?: T
}

export type State<T> = ResolvedState<T> | RejectedState<T> | PendingState<T>

function map<T, U>(state: ResolvedState<T>, mapper: (data: T) => U): ResolvedState<U>
function map<T, U>(state: RejectedState<T>, mapper: (data: T) => U): RejectedState<U>
function map<T, U>(state: PendingState<T>, mapper: (data: T) => U): PendingState<U>
function map<T, U>(state: State<T>, mapper: (data: T) => U): State<U> {
  switch (state.status) {
    case 'resolved':
      return {
        status: 'resolved',
        data: mapper(state.data),
      }
    case 'rejected':
      return {
        status: 'rejected',
        error: state.error,
        data: state.data === undefined ? undefined : mapper(state.data),
      }
    case 'pending':
      return {
        status: 'pending',
        data: state.data === undefined ? undefined : mapper(state.data),
      }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(state: ResolvedState<number | undefined>, mapper: (data: number | undefined) => unknown): ResolvedState<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'State<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResolvedState<number | undefined>'.
      Type 'RejectedState<number>' is not assignable to type 'ResolvedState<number | undefined>'.
        Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
          Type '"rejected"' is not assignable to type '"resolved"'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(state: RejectedState<number>, mapper: (data: number) => unknown): RejectedState<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'State<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RejectedState<number>'.
      Type 'ResolvedState<number>' is not assignable to type 'RejectedState<number>'.
        Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
          Type '"resolved"' is not assignable to type '"rejected"'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(state: PendingState<number>, mapper: (data: number) => unknown): PendingState<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'State<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PendingState<number>'.
      Type 'ResolvedState<number>' is not assignable to type 'PendingState<number>'.
        Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
          Type '"resolved"' is not assignable to type '"pending"'.
```

Comment: I don't know why it would infer `mapper` to have type `(data: number | undefined) => unknown`, but that's not the actual problem with the code. Rather, "*`No overload matches this call.`*", because "*`Argument of type 'State<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResolvedState<number …>'`*" and "*`… not assignable to parameter of type 'RejectedState<number>'`*" and "*`… not assignable to parameter of type 'PendingState<number>'.`*". You also need to declare an overload that accepts a `State<number>`, not just 3 overloads that accept each individual part of the union.

Comment: I can understand that. thank you! pls write it as an answer :)

Comment: Nah actually you're right, this *should* work, apparently it's a [TypeScript bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107)